# Error when launching a JAR with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to launch a JAR with the command `scala nameJar.jar`

My Spark configuration:

```
 val sc = SparkSession.builder()
   .master("local")
   .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG3GC")
   .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG4GC")
   .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
   .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1048")
   .config("spark.driver.memory","2048")
   .appName("Lea")
   .getOrCreate()
```

Error:

```
17/06/13 09:35:29 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/06/13 09:35:29 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 239075328 must be at least 471
859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
        at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:216)
```

Comment: how do you launch your jar? runnig through IDE or spark-submit command?

Comment: scala namejar.jar

Comment: why not spark-submit ?

Comment: But how do this? I have created a jar to use it inside another program

Comment: you cant submit a spark-job with the scala command

Comment: Ok, but what I do? I m not expert in spark

Comment: Follow here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146513/discussion-between-mounir-hamdane-and-shankar-koirala).

Comment: Maybe you are using a 32bit JDK, try using 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I think the line is clear

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 239075328 must be at
>   least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory
>   option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.

You need to increase the driver-memory by 
`--driver-memory 1g` while running

If you are using maven then

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

or you can pass the VM options argument in intellij and eclipse as

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used this command :  scala data
integrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:P
ermSize=1024m But I have a same error

Comment: In your configuration  .config("spark.driver.memory","2048") use  .config("spark.driver.memory","1g") should work i think

Comment: aren't you trying to run spark job ? If so you must use spark-submit

Comment: I used eclipse IDE et its worked but with a jar not working